# Date-partitioned template tables in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create [date-partitioned](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables) + [template](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template_table_details) tables in BigQuery:

1. Create base table using `bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY myapp.customer`
2. Call API `insertAll` with `"tableId": "customer", "templateSuffix": "_activated"`

The resulting `customer_activated` table inherits the schema of the `customer` table, but has no `timePartitioning`.

How can I ensure template tables inherit the time partitioning of the base table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming APIs do not yet support date-partitioning
Your option is to use load job with the partition as the destination for initial population and then just use streaming directly to the table (without using partitions) and let bigquery infer the partition timestamp

Otherwise you should wait when streaming will support date-partitioning which Google Team mentioned to happen in near future

> Update:

Since around mid-2017 BigQuery supports [Streaming into partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables)

Comment: Do you know the current status of streaming supporting date-partitioning (as of July 2017)?

Comment: @BrianLeach - it is supported now - with some limitations - When streaming using a partition decorator, you can stream to partitions within the last 30 days in the past and 5 days in the future relative to the current date, based on current UTC time - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables  . btw, consider voting up this answer as looks like it helped you (I think) to find what you were looking for :o)

Comment: Happy to upvote the answer, please consider editing it to reflect the current state of the library

Answer (score 3):

For people coming here in the future, the accepted answer is outdated. BigQuery Streaming APIs support date-partition tables now, both to the table and to a specific partition

[Link to docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables)

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, as of November 2022, it is indeed possible to stream data into **already existing** partitioned tables, however, tables created automatically using a template table do **NOT** inherit the time partitioning configuration of the parent table, which is what OP was asking in the first place.